# Django/Python encoding error while reading website

Tags: python, encoding, beautifulsoup, decoding

I want to read content of few pages on one website, for few oh them my code works ok, but for the rest of them not. Strange chars appears: Å‚Ä… and more.

```
articles = ""
url = "http://www.someurl.com"
sock = urllib.urlopen(url)

content = sock.read()
sock.close()
soup = BeautifulSoup(content)

div = soup.find("div", class_="col-d")
ps = div.find_all("p")
for p in ps:
    print type(p.get_text())
    print type(p.get_text().encode('utf-8'))
    print p.get_text()
```

The output is:

```
<type 'unicode'><type 'str'>rÃ³Å¼ni siÄ™ znaczÄ…co. DziÅ›, zgodnie z danymi Lionâ€™s House i Home Brokera, przeciÄ™tnego  zapÅ‚aciÄ‡ niespeÅ‚na 2,1 tys. zÅ‚ miesiÄ™cznie. Gdyby takÄ… samÄ… nieruchomoÅ›Ä‡ kupiÄ‡ na kredyt, to w pierwszym roku czÄ™Å›Ä‡ ods
```

**Do you know any solutions to make this work?**

Comment: What do you get when you call `print(sock.headers['content-type'])` ?

Comment: @Jason Sperske: text/html; charset=utf-8

Comment: Using the [Requests library](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) this seems to work: `print requests.get("http://pl.bab.la/slownik/polski-niemiecki/zgodnie-z").text`  Maybe your URL is incorrectly reporting it's character encoding

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7219361/python-and-beautifulsoup-encoding-issues this seems to be an issue with conflicting information

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22485/discussion-between-user985541-and-jason-sperske)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an approach that uses the [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) library (and a random Polish website).

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get("http://pl.bab.la/slownik/polski-niemiecki/zgodnie-z")

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, fromEncoding="UTF-8")
soup.find(id="showMoreCSDiv").text
```

This code looks for this HTML:

```
<div id="showMoreCSDiv"><a class="btn" id="showMoreCS" href="javascript:babGetMoreCS(20,'zgodnie z');">więcej</a></div>
```

It returns this:

```
więcej
```