# How to correctly parse UTF-8 encoded HTML to Unicode strings with BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8, beautifulsoup, urllib2

I'm running a Python program which fetches a UTF-8-encoded web page, and I extract some text from the HTML using BeautifulSoup.

However, when I write this text to a file (or print it on the console), it gets written in an unexpected encoding.

Sample program:

```py
import urllib2
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

# Fetch URL
url = 'http://www.voxnow.de/'
request = urllib2.Request(url)
request.add_header('Accept-Encoding', 'utf-8')

# Response has UTF-8 charset header,
# and HTML body which is UTF-8 encoded
response = urllib2.urlopen(request)

# Parse with BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(response)

# Print title attribute of a <div> which uses umlauts (e.g. können)
print repr(soup.find('div', id='navbutton_account')['title'])
```

Running this gives the result:

```
# u'Hier k\u0102\u015bnnen Sie sich kostenlos registrieren und / oder einloggen!'
```

But I would expect a Python Unicode string to render `ö` in the word `können` as [`\xf6`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00f6/index.htm):

```
# u'Hier k\xf6bnnen Sie sich kostenlos registrieren und / oder einloggen!'
```

I've tried passing the 'fromEncoding' parameter to BeautifulSoup, and trying to `read()` and `decode()` the `response` object, but it either makes no difference, or throws an error.

With the command `curl www.voxnow.de | hexdump -C`, I can see that the web page is indeed UTF-8 encoded (i.e. it contains `0xc3 0xb6`) for the `ö` character:

```
      20 74 69 74 6c 65 3d 22  48 69 65 72 20 6b c3 b6  | title="Hier k..|
      6e 6e 65 6e 20 53 69 65  20 73 69 63 68 20 6b 6f  |nnen Sie sich ko|
      73 74 65 6e 6c 6f 73 20  72 65 67 69 73 74 72 69  |stenlos registri|
```

I'm beyond the limit of my Python abilities, so I'm at a loss as to how to debug this further. Any advice?

Comment: Strange.. as `\u0102\u015b` is `'Ăś'`..

Comment: @justhalf I think I saw that question, but don't think I got the same results. But I'll check again, thanks.

Comment: I would lean to that answer and use requests lib and raw content
http://stackoverflow.com/a/36833440/3806595

Answer (score 40, accepted):

As justhalf points out above, my question here is essentially a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7219361/234938).

The HTML content reported itself as UTF-8 encoded and, for the most part it was, except for one or two rogue invalid UTF-8 characters.

This apparently confuses BeautifulSoup about which encoding is in use, and when trying to first decode as UTF-8 when passing the content to BeautifulSoup like 
this:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.read().decode('utf-8'))
```

I would get the error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode bytes in position 186812-186813: 
                    invalid continuation byte
```

Looking more closely at the output, there was an instance of the character `Ü` which was wrongly encoded as the invalid byte sequence `0xe3 0x9c`, rather than the correct [`0xc3 0x9c`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00dc/index.htm).

As the currently [highest-rated answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7222936/234938) on that question suggests, the invalid UTF-8 characters can be removed while parsing, so that only valid data is passed to BeautifulSoup:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.read().decode('utf-8', 'ignore'))
```

Answer (score 3):

Encoding the result to `utf-8` seems to work for me:

```
print (soup.find('div', id='navbutton_account')['title']).encode('utf-8')
```

It yields:

```
Hier kÃ¶nnen Sie sich kostenlos registrieren und / oder einloggen!
```

Comment: Hmm.. I tried on a couple of machines (with Python 2.7.3); that code gives me four bytes in place of the two you're getting for the `ö` character: `c4 82 c5 9b`