# Python 3 & BeautifulSoup Issue - [Decode error - output not utf-8]

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'm facing some problems with beautifulsoup.

I'm trying to read the title of a couple website and when my code tries to read some sites that contains title with latin charactes I get this error:

> [Decode error - output not utf-8]

Does someone knows how to solve this?

Cheers.

My code:

```
def getTitle(theList):

for element in theList:

    response = urllib.request.urlopen(element)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.read())
    title = soup.find("title").text
    print (element,": ",title,"\n")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try: [How to correctly parse UTF-8 encoded HTML to Unicode strings with BeautifulSoup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20205455/how-to-correctly-parse-utf-8-encoded-html-to-unicode-strings-with-beautifulsoup?answertab=votes#tab-top)

It suggests `soup = BeautifulSoup(response.read().decode('utf-8', 'ignore'))`

Comment: Hi Celeo, thanks fo the answer., I alreayd tried, but I still get the same error. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

If the error is due to [inconsitent encodings](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#inconsistent-encodings) i.e., the html is mostly utf-8 (and `BeautifulSoup` detects it as such) but some characters (most notably: Microsoft smart quotes) are in different encoding; try `UnicodeDammit.detwingle()` method to make the document pure UTF-8 without discarding the incorrect characters that can be salvaged.

Comment: Sebastian, I don't get it. Could you be more specific? Should I use UnicodeDammint.getwingle() inside BeautifulSoup(...)?

Comment: @user3120065: click the link. It explicitely says when you should call `.detwingle()`