# Weird HTML code looks like this b'\xff\xd8\xff\xe0

Tags: python, html

I'm using python to retrieve an HTML source, but what comes out looks like this. What is this, and why am I not getting the actual page source?

b'\xff\xd8\xff\xe0\x00\x10JFIF\x00\x01\x01\x00\x00\x01\x00\x01\x00\x00\xff\xdb\x00C

Answer (score 5):

This is an image. Specifically a jpeg. Since it's a byte stream python prints it with `b'.............'`
A jpeg starts with `\xff\xd8\xff\`

Answer (score 0):

Try using [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/)

Here's an example
[How to correctly parse UTF-8 encoded HTML to Unicode strings with BeautifulSoup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20205455/how-to-correctly-parse-utf-8-encoded-html-to-unicode-strings-with-beautifulsoup)

Basically, what you're seeing is encoded characters that need to be decoded.