# 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf6 in position 139604: invalid start byte

Tags: python, web, web-crawler, knowledge-capture

I am making a knowledge engineering project.

When I was crawling some scientists personal site, this bug occurred.

```
import html2text
import requests
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import urllib


homepage = "http://angom.myweb.cs.uwindsor.ca"
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:23.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/23.0'}
req = urllib.request.Request(url=homepage, headers=headers)
print(req)
c = urlopen(req).read()
print(type(c))

content = urlopen(req).read().decode("utf-8")
```

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf6 in position 139604: invalid start byte

Comment: `print(c[139600:139610])` would give a hint maybe?

Answer (score 0):

The encoding in the page header states:

```
<meta http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
```

.. so use that when decoding the string.

```
content = urlopen(req).read().decode("windows-1252")
```

will work in this instance.

If you are planning to use BeautifulSoup, [it already does a really good job figuring out the encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36833357/python-correct-encoding-of-website-beautiful-soup).