# Scraping Stackoverflow hyperlinks with Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm learning scraping with Beautifulsoup and am using Stackoverflow's interesting questions section ("https://stackoverflow.com/?tab=interesting") for practice.

I want to extract hyperlinks for the top 5 questions that the user has tagged with 'java' AND 
that has at least one answer (ok if the answer has been accepted but not a requirement).

I've looked at the [Beautifulsoup documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/),
but I can't get it to come together.

Thanks for any help!

CODE:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen

html = urlopen("https://stackoverflow.com/?tab=interesting")
content = html.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(content)

soup.findAll('a',{'class':'question-hyperlink'}, href = True ,  limit=5)        # question link 
soup.findAll('div', {'class':'status answered'},  limit=5)                      # question answer 
soup.findAll('a',{'class':'post-tag'}, rel ='tag' , text = 'java',  limit=5)    # question user tag
```

DESIRED OUTPUT (as hyperlinks):

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/number/first-question-to-meet-the-criteria
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/number/second-question-to-meet-the-criteria
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/number/third-question-to-meet-the-criteria
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/number/forth-question-to-meet-the-criteria
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/number/fifth-question-to-meet-the-criteria
```

Comment: _I can't get it to come together_ Can you be more specific?

Comment: If your matter is solved please mark the answer as accepted so that others can see that your question has been answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

html = requests.get("https://stackoverflow.com/?tab=interesting")
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.content)

# find and iterate over all parent divs of questions
for elem in soup.findAll('div',{'class':'question-summary narrow'}):
    # get count of answers
    answer = elem.find("div", {"class": "mini-counts"})
    if answer.text != "0":
        # check if question is tagged with "Java"
        tags = elem.find("div", {"class": "t-java"})
        if tags is not None:
            # print link  
            print(elem.find("a")["href"])
```

If you don't get a printout try changing the tag to `t-python` for example.

Comment: I believe it's recommend to use `.content`, not `.text`, to feed the result of the request to BeautifulSoup.

Comment: Why do you think so? `.content` returns byte code rather than text and therefore throws an error. `.text` yields the raw HTML as text and works fine.

Comment: There's some information on the subject [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36833357/11301900) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40163323/should-i-use-text-or-content-when-parsing-a-requests-response/40163370), for example.

Comment: Also, testing for `None` should probably be done using `is`, instead of `==`.

Comment: I stand corrected. Didn't know that. Thanks for the hint!