# Scraping page returning slashes in tags using BeautifulSoup and python

Tags: python, web-scraping, encoding, beautifulsoup

I'm scraping [this page](https://www.gob.mx/presidencia/es/archivo/articulos?filter_id=5169&filter_origin=archive&idiom=es&page=1) as a first step for capturing the links on the page for each "continuar leyendo". When I look at the html using Inspect Element, I see that I need to target all the

```
class = "small-link"
```

But when I scrape it with BeautifulSoup, the page actually returns it as

`class=\"small-link\"`

Using
`curl -i https://www.gob.mx/presidencia/es/archivo/articulos?filter_id=5169&filter_origin=archive&idiom=es&page=1`

I see the page is:

```
Content-Type: text/javascript; charset=utf-8
```

I have tried the following but it still returns the escape characters:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(site.content, "html.parser", from_encoding='utf-8')
```

Any suggestions on how to get the correct encoding returned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used urllib3 which works for python 3.7
You can find details in the [userguide](https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-guide.html)

```
import urllib3
http = urllib3.PoolManager()
request = http.request('get', 'URL-HERE')
soup = BeautifulSoup(request.data,"html.parser")
```

Answer (score 1):

The following code parsed the page without all the backslashes for me:

```
import bs4
import urllib2
request = urllib2.Request('https://www.gob.mx/presidencia/es/archivo/articulos?filter_id=5169&filter_origin=archive&idiom=es&page=1')
request.add_header('Accept-Encoding', 'utf-8')
response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response)
```

taken from this post:
[How to correctly parse UTF-8 encoded HTML to Unicode strings with BeautifulSoup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20205455/how-to-correctly-parse-utf-8-encoded-html-to-unicode-strings-with-beautifulsoup)

Comment: I keep getting a "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'urllib2'...I am using python 3.7

Comment: shoot... I'm actually using python 2- have you installed and imported `urllib2`? `pip install urllib2`

Comment: looks like urllib2 does not work for python3...says it has been split into different functions https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html

Comment: I can't get it to work in a python3 environment... but there is a `urllib3` that should work for python3- the command `urllib3.request` should work- I hope that helps- sorry I couldn't do more

Comment: In Python 3, `urllib2` has been replaced by [urllib.request](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html).   `urllib3` is a third-party library.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the `requests` module (`pip3 install requests`):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
d = soup(requests.get('https://www.gob.mx/presidencia/es/archivo/articulos?filter_id=5169&filter_origin=archive&idiom=es&page=1').text, 'html.parser')
result = [{'img':i.div.img['src'], 'time':i.time.text, 'text':i.h2.text, 'link':i.a['href']} for i in d.find_all('article')]
```

To get the links, you can loop over `result` and access the `link` key for each. The links are relative, so to create the full URL, you can use `urllib.parse`:

```
import urllib.parse
base = 'https://www.gob.mx/presidencia/es/archivo/articulos?filter_id=5169&filter_origin=archive&idiom=es&page=1'
links = [urllib.parse.urljoin(base, i['link']) for i in result]
```

Output:

```
['https://www.gob.mx/presidencia/es/articulos/version-estenografica-de-la-conferencia-de-prensa-matutina-jueves-14-de-noviembre-2019?idiom=es', 'https://www.gob.mx/presidencia/es/articulos/version-estenografica-de-la-conferencia-de-prensa-matutina-miercoles-13-de-noviembre-2019?idiom=es', 'https://www.gob.mx/presidencia/es/articulos/version-estenografica-de-la-conferencia-de-prensa-matutina-martes-12-de-noviembre-2019?idiom=es', 'https://www.gob.mx/presidencia/es/articulos/version-estenografica-de-la-conferencia-de-prensa-matutina-lunes-11-de-noviembre-2019?idiom=es', 'https://www.gob.mx/presidencia/es/articulos/version-estenografica-dialogo-con-los-pueblos-maya-peninsular-ch-ol-tsotsil-tseltal-y-poblacion-indigena-migrante-desde-calakmul?idiom=es', 'https://www.gob.mx/presidencia/es/articulos/version-estenografica-dialogo-con-el-pueblo-maya-peninsular-y-poblacion-indigena-migrante-desde-felipe-carrillo-puerto?idiom=es', 'https://www.gob.mx/presidencia/es/articulos/version-estenografica-dialogo-con-el-pueblo-maya-peninsular-desde-temozon?idiom=es', 'https://www.gob.mx/presidencia/es/articulos/version-estenografica-dialogo-con-el-pueblo-maya-peninsular-desde-tekax-de-alvaro-obregon?idiom=es', 'https://www.gob.mx/presidencia/es/articulos/version-estenografica-de-la-conferencia-de-prensa-matutina-viernes-8-de-noviembre-2019?idiom=es']
```