# Python web scrape (requests, BeautifulSoup)

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to write a simple web scrape script so I wrote this code and I got an error.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get('http://the website that I need.com')

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)

print(soup.prettify())
```

And I am getting an error saying:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "course.py", line 18, in <module>
    print(soup.prettify())
  File "C:\Python34\lib\encodings\cp437.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_map)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u203a' in position
32558: character maps to <undefined>
```

I am using Python 3.4.0

So can anyone tell what is going on?

Comment: Try use `r.text` instead of `r.content`?

Comment: i tried but it didnot work

Answer (score -1):

I belive this is a Encode problem: try add a encode type on return string with:

Exmample to encode to UTF-8
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content.encode('uft-8'))

Comment: i tried but it is not working it say : Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "course.py", line 10, in <module>
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content.encode('uft-8'))
AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'encode'

Comment: I see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7219361/python-and-beautifulsoup-encoding-issues prettify method the encode charset is possibile to set with args ex:

soup.prettify('utf-8')