# Why am I getting UnicodeEncode error?

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying to make a small parsing script and testing out waters.
I am not sure why am I getting this error

my code is

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests
r = requests.get('http://www.marca.com/en/football/real-madrid.html?intcmp=MENUPROD&s_kw=english-real-madrid')

data = r.text.encode() 

soup = bs(data,'html.parser')

print (soup.prettify())
```

and the error

```
print (soup.prettify())
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 2153-2154: ordinal not in range(128)
```

however if I use *.encode()* in my print line, it works fine.
I just want to be 100% sure I am accurate with this. Have 0 experience parsing HTML/XML

Comment: have you tried different parsers?

Comment: It should be caused by the retrieved html content has non unicode characters.

Comment: Normally one html page must declare what kind of charset it uses in its head. Give a try to get that charset name then apply appropriate decoder.

Comment: @Sphinx worked like magic. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is this

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests

req = requests.get('http://www.marca.com/en/football/real-madrid.html?intcmp=MENUPROD&s_kw=english-real-madrid')
data = req.text

soup = bs(data,'html.parser')

print (soup.prettify('latin-1'))
```

with the help of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7219361/python-and-beautifulsoup-encoding-issues/7222936)