# Encode with python and json

Tags: python, json, encryption, beautifulsoup, encode

i don't understand how work encodage with python.

```
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


soup = BeautifulSoup('A lot of HTML here', 'html.parser')
rec_titre = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "c-toparticle__title"})
trait_titre = rec_titre[0].text.replace("\n", '').strip()

dataEcho.append({'Titre': trait_titre, 'content': trait_content, 'uri': "https://www.lecho.be" + rec_uri})


with open('data.json', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(dataEcho, outfile, sort_keys=True, indent=4, separators=(',', ': '))
```

**result in my Json file :**

```
[
    {
        "Titre": "Amay | Vers un troisi\u00c3\u00a8me mandat pour Jean-Michel Javaux",
        "content": "L\u00e2\u0080\u0099ex copr\u00c3\u00a9sident d\u00e2\u0080\u0099Ecolo a demand\u00c3\u00a9 (et obtenu) une d\u00c3\u00a9rogation de son parti Ecolo pour pouvoir briguer un nouveau mandat ma\u00c3\u00aforal.",
        "uri": "https://www.lecho.be/dossier/zoom-communal/amay-vers-un-troisieme-mandat-pour-jean-michel-javaux/10032845.html"
    }
]
```

**EDIT :**

I have been looking for this morning impossible to find. I am in python3

[Code here](http://py3.codeskulptor.org/#user301_EnWMkPhiUo_0.py) || Just would like have utf-8 in my json...

**Json :**

```
[
  {
    "Titre": "Amay | Vers un troisième mandat pour Jean-Michel Javaux",
    "content": "Lâex coprÃ©sident dâEcolo a demandÃ© (et obtenu) une dÃ©rogation de son parti pour pouvoir briguer un nouveau mandat maÃ¯oral.",
    "uri": "https://www.lecho.be/dossier/zoom-communal/amay-vers-un-troisieme-mandat-pour-jean-michel-javaux/10032845.html"
  }
]
```

Comment: `json.dump(..., ensure_ascii=False)` helps?

Comment: nop i have try results : "Titre": "Amay | Vers un troisi�me mandat pour Jean-Michel Javaux",

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python and BeautifulSoup encoding issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7219361/python-and-beautifulsoup-encoding-issues)