# BeautifulSoup shows strange text

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, unicode, encoding, ascii

I am trying to scrape data from a Bengali (language) website.
When I inspect element on that website, everything is as it should.

code:

```
request = requests.get("https://corona.gov.bd/")
soup = BeautifulSoup(request.content, "lxml")
print(soup.prettify())
```

Part of the output:

```
<strong>
  à¦¸à¦à¦°à¦¾à¦à¦° à¦à¦¿à¦à§à¦à¦¾à¦¸à¦¾
</strong>
```

à¦¸à¦à¦°à¦¾à¦à¦° à¦à¦¿à¦à§à¦à¦¾à¦¸à¦¾ >> should be >>"সচরাচর জিজ্ঞাসা"

I am not sure if it is ASCII or not. I used https://onlineasciitools.com/convert-ascii-to-unicode to convert that text into Unicode. As per this website, it may be ASCII. But I checked an ASCII table online and none of those characters were in it. So now I need to convert those text into readable stuff. Any help?

Comment: check out https://stackoverflow.com/q/7219361/1216776

Comment: Use `request.text` instead.  The content will be decoded for you, assuming the website declared the encoding correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just decode the content, like this:

```
request.content.decode('utf-8')
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, its work. You need to decode('utf-8') request response.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
request = requests.get("https://corona.gov.bd/")

soup = BeautifulSoup(request.content.decode('utf-8'), "lxml")
my_data = soup.find('div', {'class':'col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 slider-button-center xs-mb-15'})
print(my_data.get_text(strip=True, separator='|'))
```

print output:

```
্বাস্থ্য বিষয়ক সেবা|(ডাক্তার, হাসপাতাল, ঔষধ, টেস্ট)|খাদ্য ও জরুরি সেবা|(খাদ্য, অ্যাম্বুলেন্স, ফায়ার সার্ভিস)|সচরাচর জিজ্ঞাসা|FAQ
```

Answer (score 0):

The request returned by `requests.get()` returns both the raw byte content (`request.content`) and and the content decoded by the encoding declared in the content.

`request.encoding` is the actual encoding (which may not be UTF-8), and `request.text` is the already-decoded content.

Example using `request.text` instead:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

request = requests.get("https://corona.gov.bd/")
soup = BeautifulSoup(request.text, "lxml")
print(soup.find('title'))
```

```
<title>করোনা ভাইরাস ইনফো ২০১৯ | Coronavirus Disease 2019 (COVID-19) Information Bangladesh | corona.gov.bd</title>
```